# HP Pavilion tx2000 - Wifi adapter no longer works after moving from 12.04 to a 12.10 clean install

Tags: 12.10, wireless, hp-pavilion

I have a HP Pavilion tx2000 that I have been running Ubuntu 12.04 on for a couple of months without any problems (wifi worked great) until yesterday when my hard drive failed. I replaced the hard drive and decided to install Ubuntu 12.10. Unlike 12.04, the wifi did not work after the installation finished and all the updates where installed (over Ethernet). The network drop down in the top right didn't even show a wireless option.

I Googled about for a bit and found some solutions that seemed like they might work. Unfortunately they did not.

Here is what I tried:

```
sudo apt-get remove bcmwl-kernel-source 
sudo apt-get install b43-fwcutter
sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-lpphy-installer
```

Restart the computer.

And the wifi still didn't work. At which point I panicked a bit and tried to undo the previous commands by running:

```
sudo apt-get remove b43-fwcutter firmware-b43-lpphy-installer
sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source
```

Restart the computer.

The wifi still doesn't work.

This is where I stopped because I have no idea what I am doing and don't want to mess something up. The network drop down still doesn't show a wireless option and the hardware wifi switch on the laptop is amber (it turns blue when the wifi is on). Using the hardware switch does not change the color.

**Output from: sudo lspci**

```
...
08:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4322 802.11a/b/g/n Wireless LAN Controller (rev 01)
...
```

**Output from: sudo lshw -class network**

```
*-network UNCLAIMED     
   description: Network controller
   product: BCM4322 802.11a/b/g/n Wireless LAN Controller
   vendor: Broadcom Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:08:00.0
   version: 01
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
   configuration: latency=0
   resources: memory:d1100000-d1103fff
...
```

**Output from: sudo rfkill list all**

```
0: hp-wifi: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: yes
```

### UPDATE:

After writing up this question tried the following command:

```
sudo rfkill unblock all
```

At first it didn't do anything but after running it about four times, *sudo rfkill list all* now returns:

```
0: hp-wifi: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
```

But the network menu still does not have a wireless option and the hardware switch still glows amber. Pushing the hardware switch turns the hard block back on and I have to run *sudo rfkill unblock all* multiple times again to turn it off.

Any help is appreciated!

### Update 2:

Full output from **sudo lspci -nn**:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] RS780 Host Bridge [1022:9600]
00:01.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] RS780/RS880 PCI to PCI bridge (int gfx) [1022:9602]
00:04.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] RS780/RS880 PCI to PCI bridge (PCIE port 0) [1022:9604]
00:05.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] RS780/RS880 PCI to PCI bridge (PCIE port 1) [1022:9605]
00:06.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] RS780 PCI to PCI bridge (PCIE port 2) [1022:9606]
00:11.0 SATA controller [0106]: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 SATA Controller [AHCI mode] [1002:4391]
00:12.0 USB controller [0c03]: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB OHCI0 Controller [1002:4397]
00:12.1 USB controller [0c03]: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI SB7x0 USB OHCI1 Controller [1002:4398]
00:12.2 USB controller [0c03]: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB EHCI Controller [1002:4396]
00:13.0 USB controller [0c03]: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB OHCI0 Controller [1002:4397]
00:13.1 USB controller [0c03]: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI SB7x0 USB OHCI1 Controller [1002:4398]
00:13.2 USB controller [0c03]: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB EHCI Controller [1002:4396]
00:14.0 SMBus [0c05]: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI SBx00 SMBus Controller [1002:4385] (rev 3a)
00:14.1 IDE interface [0101]: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 IDE Controller [1002:439c]
00:14.2 Audio device [0403]: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI SBx00 Azalia (Intel HDA) [1002:4383]
00:14.3 ISA bridge [0601]: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 LPC host controller [1002:439d]
00:14.4 PCI bridge [0604]: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI SBx00 PCI to PCI Bridge [1002:4384]
00:14.5 USB controller [0c03]: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB OHCI2 Controller [1002:4399]
00:18.0 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Family 11h Processor HyperTransport Configuration [1022:1300] (rev 40)
00:18.1 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Family 11h Processor Address Map [1022:1301]
00:18.2 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Family 11h Processor DRAM Controller [1022:1302]
00:18.3 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Family 11h Processor Miscellaneous Control [1022:1303]
00:18.4 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Family 11h Processor Link Control [1022:1304]
01:05.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI RS780M/RS780MN [Mobility Radeon HD 3200 Graphics] [1002:9612]
08:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4322 802.11a/b/g/n Wireless LAN Controller [14e4:432b] (rev 01)
09:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168B PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller [10ec:8168] (rev 02)
```

Comment: We need slightly more information: lspci _-nn_. Please edit your question to add this information.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. I have added the information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please open a terminal and do:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic
sudo apt-get install --reinstall bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo modprobe wl
```

Is it working?

Comment: Yes, that solved the problem. Thank you for your help!